# How to format streaming JSON output from Node.js?

Tags: text-processing, pipe, output, json

I have a Node.js server that uses JSON logging. When running the server locally, it outputs log entries as JSON objects which are quite tedious to read. I would like to pipe the output through a command so that it's easier to follow.

I've tried some alternatives like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) but the problem is that when Node.js server is started, it prints out a few lines that are not valid JSON and I haven't found any command that would be able to ignore invalid JSON.

Is there any ready-made command I could use or do I have to start implementing my own? Each line in the server output is a full JSON object (except those few lines at the beginning).

Comment: What do these lines look like?

Comment: Something like this:

`{"name":"myapp","hostname":"myhost.local","pid":64662,"source_file_path":"/path/to/src/connector.js","req_id":"2339717c-6c3b-4e51-a4b2-5c647efd9c25","connector":"abc123","level":"INFO","req":{"method":"GET","url":"http://backend/server/url"},"time":"2016-09-01T06:31:55.099Z","v":0,"message":"Outgoing request"}`

Comment: We're using [node-bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) for logging. It has a tool for piping and formatting the entries (just what I'm looking for), but for compatibility reasons we have renamed some properties (`msg` -> `message`, for example) and the formatting doesn't work anymore. That's because `bunyan` checks for the property names before formatting.

Comment: Is there a consistent number of "junk" header lines? Or do they have a pattern or fixed text in them that we could recognize in order to skip them?

Comment: There's always a fixed number of non-JSON log entries at startup. However, I'd prefer that those lines would be just printed out as-is. That way piping would also work if someone uses `console.log()` to print out something that is not JSON-parseable.

Answer (score 2):

if you are outputting json logs use this to view pretty json in terminal

```
node my.js | jq -R 'split("\n")|.[length  - 1]|fromjson'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't play with jq or json much, so I had to simulate an environment, but the general idea should address your problem.

Here I generate three header lines and some (fake) JSON output:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo line 1
echo line 2
echo line 3
echo real json output 1
echo real json output 2
echo real json output 3
```

and here is a script that will read three header lines, then pass the rest of the input on to the real `jq` command (or, to simulate jq, I'm passing it through sed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for((HEADLINES=3; HEADLINES > 0; HEADLINES--))
do
  IFS= read -r header
  printf "%s\n" "$header"
done

sed 's/^/parsing: /'
```

The core idea here is to `read` the desired number of header lines, print them back out unchanged, then pass the rest of the input to jq (sed, here). Replace the sed command with your desired `jq` command.

A sample run:

```
$ ./json.sh  | ./jq.sh
line 1
line 2
line 3
parsing: real json output 1
parsing: real json output 2
parsing: real json output 3
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that this only allows a fixed number of non-JSON lines. I really would need a script that does try-catch and prints the line as-is if it doesn't validate as JSON.

Comment: I'm confused; [earlier, you said](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307134/how-to-format-streaming-json-output-from-node-js#comment540155_307134) there was a fixed number of non-JSON lines.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I also said that it should handle the case when someone decides to log something directly to console. I actually decided to implement the whole thing myself with Node. I'll post it here when it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are `n` lines of non-JSON output, the following short script would pass these lines on as they are, and use `jq` to format the remaining lines.  The input is assumed to come on standard input to the script, and the script takes the number `n` from the first command line argument (or defaults to 5 if this argument does not exist).

```
#!/bin/sh

n=${1-5}

if [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; then
    head -n "$n"
fi

jq .
```

The script assumes that the `head` command will only consume exactly `n` lines of input.  There are implementations of `head` that does not behave like this and that will read more than `n` lines, leaving no input for `jq` to process.  GNU `head` is well behaved in this aspect and works as intended.

Testing:

```
$ sh script.sh 2 <file.json
non-json text
on two lines
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "hostname": "myhost.local",
  "pid": 64662,
  "source_file_path": "/path/to/src/connector.js",
  "req_id": "2339717c-6c3b-4e51-a4b2-5c647efd9c25",
  "connector": "abc123",
  "level": "INFO",
  "req": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "http://backend/server/url"
  },
  "time": "2016-09-01T06:31:55.099Z",
  "v": 0,
  "message": "Outgoing request"
}
```

---

The following is a variation on the above that adds a very simplistic detection of the start of the JSON contents in the input.  The JSON document is assumed start on the first line that has a `{` as the first character.

The script first saves the input to a temporary file (which is deleted when the script terminates), and then parses this file twice.  Once to extract the non-JSON data and then again to extract the JSON document.

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT

cat >"$tmpfile"

sed -n '/^[^{]/{p;d;}; q' <"$tmpfile"
sed -n '/^{/,$p'          <"$tmpfile" | jq .
```

Testing:

```
$ sh script.sh <file.json
non-json text
on two lines
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "hostname": "myhost.local",
  "pid": 64662,
  "source_file_path": "/path/to/src/connector.js",
  "req_id": "2339717c-6c3b-4e51-a4b2-5c647efd9c25",
  "connector": "abc123",
  "level": "INFO",
  "req": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "http://backend/server/url"
  },
  "time": "2016-09-01T06:31:55.099Z",
  "v": 0,
  "message": "Outgoing request"
}
```

If using a temporary file seems inelegant, then the following variation takes the pathname of the input file from the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh

infile=$1

sed -n '/^[^{]/{p;d;}; q' <"$infile"
sed -n '/^{/,$p'          <"$infile" | jq .
```